# Encrypt Post Data Before Sending

Tags: php, javascript, public-key-encryption, encryption

I've been searching for a solution to this problem for some time. I need a way to encrypt form data using JS. Then I need to be able to decrypt it using PHP. A public/private key system seems perfect, however I can't find any solutions or documentation on how to implement it. I really want to be able to implement this myself. I just need some resources to get me started.

And yes, I'm aware of SSL. Please don't recommend it. I don't want to invest the money unless the site is a success.

An example of public key encryption then private key decryption in any language would be very helpful.

Comment: http://www.jcryption.org/ is one option (or rapidssl.com $9.95/yr)

Comment: [First hit for "rsa javascript"](http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/) + [second hit for "rsa php"](http://stevish.com/rsa-encryption-in-pure-php)

Comment: You may have trust issues - if the information is really sensitive to your site users, then running it without SSL will seem pretty flaky.

Comment: The only way I know how to do this requires SSL.

Comment: I'm not collecting credit card information or anything really "sensitive". I just want to give some additional privacy to users. And Leigh, the first was 100% JS second was 100% PHP - neither will work for me. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try symmetric encryption using RC4:-

https://gist.github.com/2185197

However, SSL is relatively cheap these days and would be far easier, more secure and less error prone than a roll-your-own solution so I really wouldn't just write it off because you want to save money, it will save you in the long run.

Comment: You'd have to send the key in the clear. Kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to pay for SSL right now. If the site starts to be successful, I'll invest. But for now I'm doing things almost entirely free just to test the market.

Comment: @user185767 startssl.com offers free certificates for one year.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/rsa/index.php

More info:

http://area51.phpbb.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=84&t=33024&start=0

Comment: nice link, i can imagine that my plaintext will be encrypted by javascript before form were submited. then decrypted in php side.. but in that link i dont see any example to decrypt using php, can anybody explain to me how to decrypt it using php? many thanks :)

Comment: See http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/dev/rsa/index.txt . In particular the `if (isset($_POST['ciphertext']))` bit.